# Computing maximum and minimum diameter of a 3D tubular shape

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

[image]My aim is to compute the maximum and minimum diameters of a slice of a 3D tubular shape (as shown in the attached figure).
What I tried : several rotations of the skeleton of the shape to make it parallel to the Z axis and then cut the interpolated tubular shape at some voxel to get the slice.
However these rotations make lot of interpolations.  Hence, I would like to avoid these with a method that computes the diameters (max and min) without using rotations.
Any help please?

Comment: some data please.

Comment: here is the file : https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnTmYOWb-YUAaaNkcrLXHTeqws8?e=AnO2jS Thanks

Comment: ok that's beyond my experience. just some thoughts then. you have the skeleton, so you can calculate the plane of that slice and only sample/interpolate from the source data *once* (per slice). I don't see a need to resample recursively just for some rotations. you don't rotate the entire volume, you calculate the rotation and incorporate that into the transformations you use for a fresh resample from the source data.

Comment: I admit that I don't understand your idea. When you say "you can calculate the plane of that slice", it's important to know that I can't calculate that perpendicular plane which when it cuts the 3D shape will provide a slice. that's the whole question actually.

Comment: ok so in what representation does the skeleton exist?

Comment: the skeleton is just a set of voxels which represent the centerline of the shape. You can check this:  https://github.com/Image-Py/sknw

Comment: ok then you could pick each of these voxels (point coordinate), then grab the local neighborhood of voxels, and do a linear fit through that. that's your plane's normal. now you have a plane.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand well. Can you make a draw please?